# How to send div id as data with ajax in mvc3

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I would like to send div id as data  with ajax. As you can see at below I'm trying send only "fallout"

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
      var mydiv = $("#fallout").html();
       $.ajax({
           type: "get", url: "test", data: { mydata: mydiv },
             success: function (data) {

                    $("#font).html(data);
             }
         });
    </script>
```

Here is my div

```
<div id="fallout"><p id="font>"Test</p></div>
```

But it returns as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "get", url: "test", data: { mydata: $("#fallout").attr('id') },
         success: function (data)
         {
            $("#font).html(data);
         }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks when I have changed jquery version and it fixed